# Swift variable comparison where type is not known

Tags: swift

So I'm very new to Swift at the moment and am working on a class (as below).

The variable `selectedOption` can be an array of `String` or `Int` and the methods need to compare the values received against that array.

The below code works, but I don't like the fact that I'm type checking and replicating the code to compare Strings then again to compare Ints in methods `isSelected` and `removeSelectedItem`

Such as

```
    if selectedOption is String {
        return (self.selectedOption!.indexOf({ $0 as! String == selectedOption as! String }) != nil)
    } else if ( selectedOption is Int ) {
        return (self.selectedOption!.indexOf({ $0 as! Int == selectedOption as! Int })) != nil
    }
```

There must be a better way?

```
public class SearchOption {

    private var title: String
    private var allowAny: Bool
    private var allowMultiple: Bool
    private var dependencies: [SearchOption]?

    // Store the selected Item in an array of AnyObjects.
    private var selectedOption: [AnyObject]?

    init(title: String, allowAny: Bool, allowMultiple: Bool, dependencies: [SearchOption]?) {
        self.title = title
        self.allowAny = allowAny
        self.allowMultiple = allowMultiple
        self.dependencies = dependencies
    }

    public func setSelectedItem(selectedOption: AnyObject) -> Void {
        if self.selectedOption == nil || !self.allowMultiple{
            self.selectedOption = [AnyObject]()
        }
        self.selectedOption?.append(selectedOption)
    }

    public func getSelectedItem() -> [AnyObject]? {
        return self.selectedOption
    }

    public func removeSelectedItem(selectedOption: AnyObject) -> Void {
        if self.selectedOption != nil {
            if selectedOption is String {
                self.selectedOption = self.selectedOption!.filter() { $0 as! String != selectedOption as! String }
            } else if ( selectedOption is Int ) {
                self.selectedOption = self.selectedOption!.filter() { $0 as! Int != selectedOption as! Int }
            }
        }
    }

    public func isSelected(selectedOption: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        if self.selectedOption != nil {
            if selectedOption is String {
                return (self.selectedOption!.indexOf({ $0 as! String == selectedOption as! String }) != nil)
            } else if ( selectedOption is Int ) {
                return (self.selectedOption!.indexOf({ $0 as! Int == selectedOption as! Int })) != nil
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    public func clearSelectedItems() -> Void {
        self.selectedOption = nil
    }

    public func checkDependencies() -> Bool {
        if dependencies != nil {
            for dependency in dependencies! {
                if dependency.getSelectedItem() == nil {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }

}

var make: SearchOption = SearchOption(title: "Make", allowAny: true, allowMultiple: true, dependencies: nil)
make.setSelectedItem("Vauxhall")
make.setSelectedItem("Mazda")
make.setSelectedItem("Audi")
print(make.getSelectedItem())
make.removeSelectedItem("Mazda")
print(make.getSelectedItem())
print(make.isSelected("Audi"))
```

Outputs:

```
Optional([Vauxhall, Mazda, Audi])
Optional([Vauxhall, Audi])
true
```

Comment: I'm not at all clear on what you're actually trying to do, but you should start by eliminating code and creating the absolute simplest example possible to replicate what you're trying to do.

Comment: Will [selectedOption] be either all strings or all ints? If so, consider making the class generic based on the type the selectedOption array contains and get rid of the all the AnyObject types in the code.

Comment: @WayneTanner yes they will only ever contain one type. I've tried generics, but when I get to `setSelectedItem` it complains when I try to initialise the array with `self.selectedOption = [T]()` with Cannot assign a value of type '[T]' to a value of type '[T]'. Also when trying to append to the array in `setSelectedItem` is complains Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(T)'

Comment: The common protocol conformance of `String` and `Int` is `Printable` (Swift1) / `CustomStringConvertible` (Swift 2). Use the protocol as type and wrap the variables in the literal initializer form `"\(foo)"`.

Comment: @vadian that's beautiful thank you!

Comment: `String` and `Int` are both `Equatable`, and that is all you should need.

Comment: MartinR, vadian, WayneTanner thank you, managed to solve it using a bit of all your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on the comments already made to the question: You should make
the class *generic*, so that it can be used with `String` or `Int`
items. What you need is that the items can be compared with `==`,
i.e. that the type is `Equatable`.

The class declaration would then be

```
public class SearchOption<T : Equatable> {
   // ...
}
```

and all occurrences of `AnyObject` have to be replaced by `T`.

The `isSelected` method simplifies to

```
public func isSelected(selectedOption: T) -> Bool {
    if self.selectedOption != nil {
        return self.selectedOption!.contains( { $0 == selectedOption })
    }
    return false
}
```

which can be further simplified using *optional chaining*
and the *nil-coalescing operator* `??`:

```
public func isSelected(selectedOption: T) -> Bool {
    return self.selectedOption?.contains( { $0 == selectedOption }) ?? false
}
```

Similarly:

```
public func removeSelectedItem(selectedOption: T) -> Void {
    self.selectedOption = self.selectedOption?.filter( { $0 != selectedOption } )
}
```

For `String` items you would then create an instance of the class
with

```
let make = SearchOption<String>(title: "Make", allowAny: true, allowMultiple: true, dependencies: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve the problem using Generics and Equatable (I've never really used these before so forgive me)

In the class T is constrained to a type of Equatable, which seems to keep `.filter()` and `.indexOf` happy.

When creating the instance you pass the type you'll be using:

```
var make: SearchOption = SearchOption<String>(title: "Make", allowAny: true, allowMultiple: true, dependencies: nil)
```

The resulting class looks as follows

```
public class SearchOption<T: Equatable> {

    private var title: String
    private var allowAny: Bool
    private var allowMultiple: Bool
    private var dependencies: [SearchOption]?

    // Store the selected Item in an array of AnyObjects.
    private var selectedOption: [T]?

    init(title: String, allowAny: Bool, allowMultiple: Bool, dependencies: [SearchOption]?) {
        self.title = title
        self.allowAny = allowAny
        self.allowMultiple = allowMultiple
        self.dependencies = dependencies
    }

    public func setSelectedItem(selectedOption: T) -> Void {
        if self.selectedOption == nil || !self.allowMultiple {
            self.selectedOption = [T]()
        }
        self.selectedOption?.append(selectedOption)
    }

    public func getSelectedItem() -> [T]? {
        return self.selectedOption
    }

    public func removeSelectedItem(selectedOption: T) -> Void {
        if self.selectedOption != nil {
            self.selectedOption = self.selectedOption!.filter() { $0 != selectedOption }
        }
    }

    public func isSelected(selectedOption: T) -> Bool {
        if self.selectedOption != nil {
            return (self.selectedOption!.indexOf({ $0 == selectedOption }) != nil)
        }
        return false
    }

    public func clearSelectedItems() -> Void {
        self.selectedOption = nil
    }

    public func checkDependencies() -> Bool {
        if dependencies != nil {
            for dependency in dependencies! {
                if dependency.getSelectedItem() == nil {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }

}

var make: SearchOption = SearchOption<String>(title: "Make", allowAny: true, allowMultiple: true, dependencies: nil)
make.setSelectedItem("Vauxhall")
make.setSelectedItem("Mazda")
make.setSelectedItem("Audi")
print(make.getSelectedItem())
make.removeSelectedItem("Audi")
print(make.getSelectedItem())
print(make.isSelected("Mazda"))
```